# Redirecting a Segfault error message to a file from a C++ program

Tags: bash

I am getting a Segfault error message outputing after running this command in terminal:

```
   bash-3.2$ a.out < testfiles/inputs/tst1.txt 2> err.txt 
   [2]+  Done                    gedit err.txt
   Segmentation fault
```

a.out is just running a sorting algorithm.

Now my question is how can I redirect the Seg fault error message into the err.txt file.

Using 2> or other varitaions do not seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$ { ./a.out; } 2> err.txt
```

Comment: I didn't have success with this in a bash script.

Comment: @Evan Hmmm.  It works for me (bash 3.2.48 and Darwin 10.8.0)  I'll try some other machines later today.  What's your platform?  Try `{ sh -c './a.out'; } 2> err.txt`

Comment: That would be nice if that would also include another messages. I tried e.g. `{ ./a &>log; } &>>log`, and that didn't work.

Comment: If you want to also redirect stdout, the syntax would be `{ cmd; } 2> err.txt 1>&2`  (the `1` is redundant, and you can simply write `>&2`).  I strongly discourage the bashism which would allow you to write `{ cmd; } &> log`

Answer (score 0):

Using redirection, you can't. It is not the output of your program, but the output of the program that is running your program. And anyway, redirecting it would be generally be A Bad Idea.